# All code files in VS2015 are getting checked out

Tags: c#, github, visual-studio-2015

I am facing a very weird issue in VS2015. All code files are getting checked out by default as soon as I download a code from github repo. when I go to Team Explorer -> Changes it shows each and every file in that solution under "Pending Changes" section. But when I compare the changed file there are no changes in it.

Can anyone help me identify the issue with this. I have searched a lot but haven't found similar issue reported by anyone.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Did you clone a repo?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ : Yes I did

Comment: That's why, do you know how git works? When you clone a repository it clones into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository and then creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.